How to complete this proof of Newtonian gravity from areal velocity?
I am trying to prove the following statement

Let $F(M,m,r)$ be a mutual force law between two masses such that for
any mass $M$, the circular orbit of any test particle $m$ at a
distance equal to the Compton length of $M$ has the same areal speed
$\dot A_0$ independent of $M$ and $m$. Then the function has the
closed form \begin{equation}
     F(M,m,r) = G_0 {M m \over r^2} \end{equation} for some constant $G_0$.

Where the Compton length of a mass is defined as $r_M \equiv \hbar /Mc$ with two universal constants $\hbar,c$ having respective units of angular momentum and speed. The idea is to reverse the expression of areal speed, that -as mentioned by @Winter below- in $G=\hbar=c=1$ units is $\frac12 \sqrt{Mr}$
My argument goes very straightforward

For any test particle $m$, its angular momentum is  \begin{equation}2
 m \dot A_0 = r_M m v,\end{equation} where $v$ is the tangential speed
of the particle. The force in this situation is \begin{equation} 
 F(M,m,r_M)= {m\over r_M} v^2 =  {c \; m M \over \hbar} {4 A_0^2 \over
 r_M^2} \left[{ c M r_M \over \hbar}\right]^n \end{equation} For the
force to be mutual, ie symmetrical under the exchange $m
 \leftrightarrow M$, we need $n=0$. Now lets define  \begin{equation}
     G_0 \equiv 4 {c \dot A_0^2 \over \hbar} = 4 { \hbar c \over M_0^2} \end{equation}
(where $M_0\equiv \hbar/cL_0$ and $L_0 \equiv c \dot A_0$)
and we see that we get the expected functional form $F(M,m,r_M)$ for any $M,m$

But I am not sure if this generalises for any value of $r$ or what conditions should be added to the proposition in order to obtain the generalisation. For instance, it could be asked the F is a closed form of the input variables, or a analytical expression, or similar.
EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, there are some counterexamples based on force functions that intersect $F$. For instance let
$$H(M,m,r)= \frac{G_0Mm}{(\hbar/c)^2}\left[M^2+m^2+Mm - \frac{r}{\hbar/c} (M+m)M m  \right] \\ =
{G_0Mm}\left[\frac{1}{r_M^2}+\frac{1}{r_m^2}+\frac{1}{r_m r_M} - {r} \left(\frac{1}{r_M}+\frac{1}{r_m}\right)\frac{1}{r_m r_M}\right]$$
It is symmetric under the exchange $M\leftrightarrow m$ and we still have $H(M,m,r_M)=G_0 Mm/r^2_M$
So the question is how to discard this kind of solutions.

Is this physics or math? If you want to argue as a physicist then we have more arguments up our sleeves. For example one can argue that we need $\dot{A}(M,r) = f(Mr)$ since this has to be independent of $M$ at $r = 1/M$ (so basically assuming the function is "analytical"). Then assuming $F(m,M) = F(M,m)$ we get $\dot{A}(M,r) \propto \sqrt{Mr}$ and it follows for all $r$. However read as a purely mathematical problem it does not seem to be true, as we only have information about the force at one single distance (so we can add a force $f(r-r_M)$ with $f(0)=0$ and everything still holds).

Also why do you introduce $(...)^n$ when the $...$ is exactly unity?

@Winther I was thinking more in mathematical terms, to guess the minimal addition to the requirements (surely some analyticity, or perhaps just existence of a closed form). It was because of that that I added the power of unity, because I could then reproduce different closed forms and isolate one.

By the way, @winther, are you aware in the [astro]physics literature of this statement or the reversal one (that a particle sweeping one unit of Planck area in one unit of Planck time must be orbiting at four times the Compton length of M, for any M)?

Nope. This is more of a "fun-fact" as Newton's theory is not applicable at such small scales and at such small times anyway (those are in the realm of quantum theory).

One powerful counterexample is the family of "pseudomasive pseudogravities"
$$ G_0 M m I_0^{ -(2 - n) } \cdot \left( \frac{ M^{ M } }{ m^{ m } } \right)^{ \frac{ 2 - n }{ M - m } } \cdot \left( \frac{ M }{ m } \right)^{ - \frac{ (2 - n) M m }{ I_0 (M - m) } r } \cdot r^{-n}
$$

as for $0<n<2$ they still have a shape similar to the inverse square force and intercepting it in two points for each pair (M,m).
The only way I see to exclude this family is to ask the force to have only one coupling constant, as the one in the exponent, the transformation factor $I_0\equiv \hbar /c $, is unavoidable.
Honestly all of them are rejected by Bertrand's theorem, but invoking it is a more strict requirement in my oppinion.
